# Magento Specifications (Additional Data = Attributes) not showing ONLY on two product pages??

Tags: magento, attributes, specifications

I’m scratching my head over this one as I can’t quite figure out what’s going on.

The Specifications tab is supposed to show all the attributes for these two products, but there’s nothing shown here:

http://www.centurioncctv.com/index.php/outlet/recordersoutlet/hd16p.html 
http://www.centurioncctv.com/index.php/outlet/recordersoutlet/hd08p.html

These two products are in the Digital Recorders Attribute set, just like the rest of these DVRs on other pages...

All of these DVRs show Specifications (Additional Data) correctly....  but why only on the two pages above nothing would show...?

Please share some ideas with me…

I’ve tried recreating the product (not duplicating), but the result is the same.

Does anyone know where to start?  I know that it has something to do with view.phtml… or something.  Or is it that perhaps the folder in which the attributes are stored have wrong permission?

Does anyone know where to look for permission status for certain products’ attributes??

I also added “Downloads” and they are also not shown…

Anyone?  Please help?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The additional attributes are actually rendered if you look at the generated page source. There seems to be a `<div>` nesting error in the description content, so the javascript selector to show the attributes doesn't work correctly.
I suggest cleaning up the HTML for the description, and the other tab should start working again.